# How to get firestore collection keys?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

In the context of firestore functions, I want to retrieve all the keys of a collection, such as

[image]

and get `['94kPGjaJftEvgrimV6hX', '9CyrzLigstcpd0J8yeZN', '9m3tb7bbLR9pnjU8MG9u' ...]`.